# Symfony don't update date field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Controller, I want change two values in my entity (only for index "3) :

```
$cle->getVersions()[0]->getLots()[3]->setTantieme(97);
$cle->getVersions()[0]->getLots()[3]->setDateSuppression(new \DateTime);
dump($cle);
$em->flush();
```

But, only "Tantieme" value is changed. I don't understand. In my entity, I have :

```
  /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_suppression", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $date_suppression;

public function setDateSuppression($date_suppression)
{
    $this->date_suppression = $date_suppression;
}

public function getDateSuppression()
{
    return $this->date_supppression;
}
```

**It is a trait** . And it works great with others entities.

Dump result juste before flush :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjvke.png)

Tantieme is always updated, but date_suppression never ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to return "something" in your `setDateSuppression()` method:

```
public function setDateSuppression($date_suppression)
{
     $this->date_suppression = $date_suppression;

     return $this;
}
```

EDIT:

Try like that :

```
$cle->getVersions()[0]->getLots()[3]->setDateSuppression(new \DateTime());
```